# How to pass kwargs in ruby function? Based on python example

Tags: python, ruby, keyword-argument

#### Env:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

#### Question:

There is example on python:

```
def any_func(a, b=2, c = 0, d=None):
    return c

print(any_func(25, c=30))  # will print 30
```

How can I do the same on ruby?
How "kwargs" is called on ruby? I would like to know it for further searching.

I tried following code on ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
def any_func(a, b = 2, c = 0, d = nil)
  c
end

puts any_func(25, c = 30)  # will print 0, 30 is expected
```

Comment: In Ruby `b = 2` is always a variable assignment.

Comment: @tadman yeah :) I've read it in https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Arguments (link from comments below)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby you need to use hash-like syntax

```
def any_func(a, b: 2, c: 0, d: nil)
  c
end

any_func(25, c: 30)
```

`def fun(a=1)` only sets a default value. And if you have `any_func(25, c = 30)`, it means "call `any_func` with two arguments, 25 and result of expression `c = 30` (that is 30)"

[Read more](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/06/rubys-method-arguments/)

Answer (score 5):

Ruby has both positional arguments and keyword arguments. Differing from Python, you can't mix them  but have to declare them with their respective syntax and provide them accordingly in method calls.

```
def any_func(a, b: 2, c: 0, d: nil)
  c
end

puts any_func(25, c: 30)
```

You can refer to the [official syntax documentation](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Arguments) to learn more about how to declare and call methods with arguments.

As for your own example of calling your `any_func` method with `any_func(25, c = 30)`, what happened here is that you have created the local variable `c` in the calling context with the value `30`. You have also passed this value to the second (optional) argument `b` of your method.